# I am getting a , after my result after mysql insert

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

Hello everyone I am getting a, after my result in the databases here is my code

```
<input type="text" size="49" maxlength="40" name="image2">

$_SESSION['image'] = $image ;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO adds  (username, url, coins, image) VALUES('".$_SESSION['username']."','".$_SESSION['url']."', '".$_SESSION['perclick'].",', '".$_SESSION['image'].",'  )  ") or
```

die(mysql_error());

So if there is nick in side `$_SESSION['image']` it would show has nick, in the db the column is `varchar` if I change it to `int` and enter a number it adds the number with out the , at the end

Answer (score 1):

The quotes in the query are what are confusing. Let me use PHP's inline variables to help make this more clear.

```
"VALUES('{$_SESSION['username']}','{$_SESSION['url']}', '{$_SESSION['perclick']},', '{$_SESSION['image']},' ) ") or die(mysql_error());
```

As is hopefully now evident, what is being inserted as `image` is actually `{$_SESSION['image']},`. Also be aware that the same thing is occurring for `coins`.

Answer (score 1):

```
VALUES (
  '".$_SESSION['username']."',
  '".$_SESSION['url']."',
  '".$_SESSION['perclick'].",', // here is one
  '".$_SESSION['image'].",'     // and here's another
)
```

should be like this

```
VALUES (
  '".$_SESSION['username']."',
  '".$_SESSION['url']."',
  '".$_SESSION['perclick']."',
  '".$_SESSION['image']."'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

VALUES('".$_SESSION['username']."','".$_SESSION['url']."', '".$_SESSION['perclick']."', '".$_SESSION['image']."' )